# Media max-width vs min-width , shift 1 px

Tags: css

what is right settings when using `max-width vs min-width`

`max-width(99px) and min-width(100px)` (what about `1px` between then ?)
or
`max-width(100px) and min-width(100px)` (which will be applied for `100px` here ? )

Comment: The amount of pixels should be read as: `is equal to or narrower than x pixels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `media-queries` on a specific element and target both `max` and `min-width`, you should use the same pixel value for each. For example, the `min-width: 800px` specify the styles when over 800px in screen width. `max-width: 800px` specifies the style changes on 800px and below. Using the same value for both queries insures that the specified styles are executed.

So in your example, the `1px` between won't be a factor because there are no pixels between `99` and `100px` and you have styles specified for both. If you used `798px` instead of 799 there would be `1px` where the element defaults to the non-media styles (if any).

Note: the `max-width` styles will prioritize over the `min-width` styles if using the same value when at `800px`.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  img {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
  }
  
  .img {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
</div>
```